# Is there any better approach to generate radio button?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl, el

To generate dynamic radio button based on value in `hobby`.What i does is-

```
request.setAttribute("hobby", null);
//values of hobby can be "hobby1" or "hobby2" or "hobby3" or null
request.getRequestDispatcher("display.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

In display.jsp I am generating radio button-

```
<tr>
    <td >Hobby1
    <c:choose> 
    <c:when test='${hobby.equals("hobby1")}'>
           <input type="radio"  value="hobby1" name="hobby" checked/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    <input type="radio" value="hobby1" name="hobby"/>
    </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose> 
    </td>   
    <td >Hobby2
    <c:choose> 
    <c:when test='${hobby.equals("hobby2")}'>
           <input type="radio"  value="hobby2" name="hobby" checked/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    <input type="radio" value="hobby2" name="hobby"/>
    </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose> 
    </td>
    <td >Hobby3
    <c:choose> 
    <c:when test='${hobby.equals("hobby3")}'>
           <input type="radio"  value="hobby3" name="hobby" checked/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    <input type="radio" value="hobby3" name="hobby"/>
    </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Is there any better approach to generate radio button since now we are writing static code for each button.We are checking for each button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You don't need JSTL. EL is enough.

Try this

```
<input type="radio"  value="hobby3" name="hobby" ${(hobby == 'hobby3')?'checked':''} />
```

Comment: Is using `${(hobby == 'hobby3')` is right or we should use `${(hobby.equals("hobby3"))`?means Is operator `==` in jstl return true if they are different object having same value?

Comment: you can do both. EL works with values and not object reference. moreover method call is not supported in older containders.

Comment: you can also use `eq`.